# Search for exact string

Tags: bash

I'm trying to search for exact string located in chars number 4-7.
When I run the `cut` command on terminal it works,
however in a script it fails as I believe the if statement provide me "0".
This is what I've done:

```
for NAME in `cat LISTS_NAME`; do
if [[ John == cut -c 4-7 "${NAME}" ]]; then 
   Do Something ...
fi
if [[ Dana == cut -c 4-7 "${NAME}" ]]; then 
  Do Something... 
fi
```

Can you advise me how to run this using `cut` or any other reg-ex?

Comment: Uf, uf, many things to be improved here. Probably better to say `while IFS= read chars; do ... done < <(cut -c4-7 file)`

Answer (score 1):

Your script has many problems and you don't need `cut`. Use it this way:

```
while read -r line; do
   if [[ "${line:3:4}" == "John" ]]; then 
      Do Something ...
   elif [[ "${line:3:4}" == "Dana" ]]; then 
     Do Something... 
   fi
done < LISTS_NAME
```

In BASH `"${line:3:3}"` is same as `cut -c 4-7`

---

**EDIT:** If you don't want precise string matching then you can use:

```
while read -r line; do
   if [[ "${line:3}" == "John"* ]]; then 
      Do Something ...
   elif [[ "${line:3}" == "Dana"* ]]; then 
     Do Something... 
   fi
done < LISTS_NAME
```

Comment: Probably should be `${line:3:4}`... After all, "John" contains 4 characters, and `cut -c 4-7` returns 4 characters...

Comment: How about `[[ ${line:3} == John* ]]`? this would be easier to generalize to longer names without counting the characters `:D`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is a good idea. I have added it in EDIT section of my answer with a note to OP.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't running the `cut` command there. You are comparing `John` and `Dana` to the **literal string** `cut -c 4-7 <value-of-$NAME>`.

You need to use:

```
if [[ John == $(cut -c 4-7 "${NAME}") ]]; then
```

etc.

That being said you should only do the cut call once and store that in a variable. And for exact matching you need to quote the right-hand side of `==` to avoid globbing. So

```
substr=$(cut -c 4-7 "${NAME}")
if [[ John == "$substr" ]]; then
```

And then to avoid needing duplicate `if ...; then` lines you could do better with a `case` statement:

```
substr=$(cut -c 4-7 "${NAME}")
case $substr in
    John)
         Do something
    ;;
    Dana)
         Do something else
    ;;
esac
```